# Extjs: Is it possible for Vbox child items to have different values for align?

Tags: extjs, layout, extjs4.2

So, in ext, `vbox` layout has `align` config which can take values like `right`, `left`, `center` and so on. This value is then applied to all its children.

My question is this: what if i want the first child to be left aligned and the rest to be right aligned? How do I override the value given in layout config by default?

For exanple:

```
    xtype : 'panel',
    layout : {
            type : 'vbox',
            align : 'right'
        },
        items : [{
            xtype: 'text',
            text: 'Override right align here',
            align: 'left'

        },{
                xtype: 'text',
                text: 'Inherit default align here'
        }]
```

There is no align config for `text` or other xtypes. How do I achieve this layout. PS - I have a lot of child items, not just two. And I kinda need to stick with vbox.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this via using a few item blocks

```
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'panel',
            layout: {
                type: 'vbox',
                align: 'right'
            },
            items:[
                ...
            ]
        },
        {
            xtype: 'panel',
            layout: {
                type: 'vbox',
                align: 'left'
            },
            items:[
                ...
            ]
        },
        {
            xtype: 'panel',
            layout: {
                type: 'vbox',
                align: 'right'
            },
            items:[
                ...
            ]
        },
    ]
```

[**Look at this**](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/9cv)

Comment: Thanks for answering, this is what I'm doing currently (except I'm using hbox for the children), but I'm looking for something more elegant.

Comment: i think no more solutions ) You cant change layout for block